# Getting location from given path of a file in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a variable like `aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx.html` and I need to create the path in the makefile. So I need to trim the location of the file from given variable and create the path using `mkdir -p aaa/bbb/ccc`. How can I get the location (`aaa/bbb/ccc`) from the variable (`aaa/bbb/ccc/xxx.html`) in the makefile?

Comment: Try [$(dir names...)](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) or `dirname` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make's `dir` function extracts the directory part of a path:

```
mkdirp -p $(dir $@)
```

generates the directory of the rule's target, for example. Compare `notdir` and the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: I don't know why but `$(dir $@)` returns path with a double quote at the beginning like `"aaa/bbb/ccc/`

Comment: @onuR: Probably resulting from double quotes in $@. Without your actual Makefile, there is no way to tell.